# playing single video in multiple forms in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, video

if i have mediaplayer1 in Form1 and mediaplayer2 in Form2 than how can i play and control a single video file in both mediaplayer1 and mediaplayer2 in vb.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class file with a variable in it and everytime that you wanted to play the video, you could reference to the variable in your class.

```
Public Class MySound
     Public mysound as String = "C:/Sound"
End Class
```